# problem regarding unbiased coin toss

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A fair coin is tossed six times. What is the probability that neither heads nor tails occur three times in succession?

Comment: I'm trying to organize this by solving the contrapositive-i.e. there is a succession of either 3 heads or 3 tails. If $A_i$ denote the said event starting with the ith toss $(1\le i\le 6)$ then we have to find $P((A_1)  or (A_2) or (A_3) or A_4)$ and I stuck at this point.

Comment: It is possible to write down all possible outcomes and find the ratio of the number of favourable cases and the total number of cases but I'm trying to solve this using combinatorics.

Comment: That is better. I am not sure you would get credit for writing all possibilities in an exam anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 64 possibilities in total.

3 consecutive heads: $2\cdot4+2\cdot2=12$

4 consecutive heads: $2\cdot2+1\cdot1=5$

5 consecutive heads: $2$

6 consecutive heads: $1$

The same can be done to tails, but be aware HHHTTT and TTTHHH are in both cases.

Therefore the probability is $\frac{64-38}{64}=\frac{13}{32}$

Comment: Depending on the position of the consecutive heads/tails, there are different possibilities. For example, if 3 consecutive heads are the first three, then there are 4 possibilities (5th and 6th can be either head or tail). If they are 2nd, 3rd and 4th then there are only two possibilities.

Comment: Could you please explain your steps more clearly?

Comment: Which step don't you understand?

Comment: How do you get the number of 3 consecutive heads to be $2\cdot 4+2\cdot 2$ and that of 4 consecutive heads to be $2\cdot 2+1\cdot 1$?

Comment: If the 3 consecutive heads are the first three or the last three, then the 5th and the last (or the 1st and 2nd) can be either head or tail, where the 4th or third have to be tail. (otherwise it's four consecutive heads) If the 3 consecutive heads appears in the middle, then the one in front of it and after must both be tails. Therefore only the first or last can be either head or tail. That's $2\cdot2$(in the middle)$+2\cdot4$(first or last three). A similar argument holds for the 4 consecutive ones.

Comment: Thank u once again. Please refer me some combinatorics books or links to improve my problem-solving skill as I'm very poor at that. I need your sincere help.

Comment: Well I learn some stuff by just searching permutations/graph theory/whatever you want to search up. Put pdf at the end and there are usually good books. For instance, I found a 500 pages book about real analysis (which I am learning right now) online.